# Use String Join in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have TxtGamblerImput.Text = `2 4 6 8 10` how should that work that code? how can use that code in that textbox?

TextBox4.Text = String.Join(" ", myFirstComb)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'This your First Combination, maximal widht = element
    Dim Content As String = TxtGamblerImput.Text
    'This Your Element
    Dim Element As Integer = 5
    Dim myFirstComb = (From mVal In Content.ToString.Split() Select Convert.ToInt32(mVal)).ToArray
    'This Your Result List
    Dim MyList As New List(Of String)

    Dim myM As Integer = myFirstComb.Length
    Dim myPost = myM
    For myCnt = myM To 1 Step -1
        Dim LastStr = ""
        For mycnt3 = 1 To Element
            For myCnt2 = myCnt To myM
                'If myCnt2 = myM Then MsgBox("T")
                Dim myVal = myFirstComb(myCnt2 - 1)
                If myVal > Element Then myVal = 1
                If Element - myM + myCnt2 = myVal Then
                    myFirstComb(myCnt2 - 1) = myVal
                Else
                    If (myVal + 1) > Element Then myVal = 0
                    myFirstComb(myCnt2 - 1) = myVal + 1
                End If
            Next
            Dim Hsl = String.Join(" ", myFirstComb)
            If LastStr <> Hsl Then
                MyList.Add(Hsl)
            End If
            LastStr = Hsl
        Next
    Next
    myFirstComb = (From mVal In Content.ToString.Split() Select Convert.ToInt32(mVal))
    TextBox4.Text = String.Join(" ", myFirstComb)
End Sub
```

In that Output: Show `2 4 6 8 10`

I dind't work? How can use that code for worked?

Comment: There's an awful lot of code there, considering you seem to suggest that the output should be exactly the same as the input.  Maybe you could explain to us what all that code is supposed to be achieving.  You might also consider explaining what actually happens when you run the code.  That doesn't just mean the end result either.  You MUST debug your code before posting here, i.e. set a breakpoint, step through the code and examine the state at each step.  You need to explain EXACTLY where and how the behaviour of the code differs from your expectation.

Comment: Could you tell us what mVal is?  That seems to be pretty key to what you're wanting to do here

Comment: @Hursey `mVal` is a range variable which refers to each element in the array returned by `Content.Split()`.